# Schengen Visa refused by UAE Greek Embassy

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, greece, schengen-visas

I applied for a Schengen visa from the UAE Greek embassy. The visa was refused with the reason reason

> information provided regarding justifications for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable.

I was trying to understand the reason and I hope the following should be the one.

I applied alone with all documents and the reason I gave is Honeymoon travel. I didn't mention any information about my fiancée's passport as she has Oman residency and she will apply through the Oman embassy.

The documents that I submitted are

- visa form
- Noc from sponsor
- confirmed travel tickets for me and my fiance. Complete itinerary
- accomodation confirmations
- bank statement with sufficient balance and travel insurance

Another reason I think: I am travelling to Europe from India and returning to India. But I provided the round-trip tickets from UAE to India also. Maybe this travel is a bit confusing.

I wanted to reapply. Should I apply again with the same documents, only adding my fiancée's passport detaila and stating she applied separately for a Schengen visa? Or should I book full-flex airline tickets from UAE to Europe and reapply with changed itinerary so it will be simple to understand?

Or I can apply for different embassy with different bookings as I heard reapplying for Greece Embassy is tough to get again?

Or please provide your valuable opinions and advise.

Comment: Is "Noc" a "No-Objection Certificate"?

Comment: Yes. No objection and leave confirmation